# How to inject the maximum acoustic power into a block of granite?

Tags: acoustics, power

I know that we can use transducers that are glued to a surface to achieve this. If I want, for example, to have 200 watts of actual acoustic power in the audible range in the granite, is a transducer the easiest cheapest way? Are there other methods?

Comment: transducer: n. a device that receives a signal in the form of one type of energy and converts it to a signal in another form. So unless your intention is to get preexisting ambient acoustic power into the granite, you will indeed need a transducer of some sort.

Comment: Do you just want to deliver 200 watts *through* the granite (and have most of it come out the other side), or do you want the granite to actually absorb 200 watts (thereby heating the granite by that much)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the challenge you have to overcome.

To actually deliver 200 watts of acoustic power into a solid block of granite requires that the transducer be *impedance-matched* to the *load*.

If you press on a piece of granite, it presses back really hard and experiences almost no compression in response. This makes it an ultrahigh impedance load, and if your transducer impedance is lower than this, most of the acoustic energy will bounce right off the block and not enter it. Your transducer might be producing 200 watts but 199 of that is reflected off the block; meanwhile you are still pumping 200 watts into the transducer, and it will soon blow up.

This effect rules out the use of any sort of moving-coil loudspeaker as a transducer because they are all designed to drive a very low impedance load: the air in front of the cone.

You are pretty much restricted to piezoelectric-type transducers, as used in very large ultrasonic welding machines, but even then you will need a custom-fabricated *horn assembly* which will match the impedance of the piezo transducer stack to that of the rock at the frequency of interest. This sort of setup will cost of order ~tens of thousands of dollars.

Note that typical piezoelectric ultrasonic welding machines operate at and above 40 kilohertz. To drive 200 watts into a chunk of rock in the audio range will require many, many transducers.

BTW, what exactly are you wanting to accomplish with such a setup?

Comment: The "frequency of interest" apparently is the audible range, which is rather broad (conventinally 20Hz-20kHz, factor of 1000). Matching impedance over the whole band is going to be a _big_ challenge.

Comment: I already tried using a resonance speaker (some call it an exciter) that I glued to the surface of a granite disk. Although I can hear the sound that is produced, I am pretty sure that the actual acoustic power inside the bulk of the material is not very high. And most probably, the vibration is not in the direction I want it. I am going to create a new question detailing my experiment. In particular, I want longitudinal acoustic waves to travel from the center of my granite disk to its outer diameter.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use an industrial size [vibrator motor](https://www.google.com/search?q=industrial%20vibrator%20motor&hl=en&tbm=isch) bolted to the granite. The motor shaft has an eccentric mass on it which will vibrate at the rotational frequency of the motor. Not enough power? Use more than one.
2. Use a [plate compactor](https://www.google.com/search?q=plate%20compactor&tbm=isch) if the process can be conducted outdoors.
3. Use a [jackhammer](https://www.google.com/search?q=pneumatic%20jackhammer&tbm=isch), or its smaller cousin, an electric demolition hammer. If you don't want a hole in the granite, cut off the pointy end of the bit and weld a thick flat plate to spread the impact over a larger area.

I have no idea if any of these methods will deliver 200 watts of power to the granite, but the power will be in the acoustic range and the cost is low enough to try it and take measurements. Not to mention the fun factor.

Comment: Brilliant suggestions! Before seeing your answer, I was thinking along the lines of: what if I hit the surface with a hammer? Because I am interested in a pulse of sound, not necessarily a nice sinusoid.