# How to generate longitudinal acoustic waves in a granite disk. Starting from the center going outwards like dropping a rock in a pond

Tags: gravity, acoustics

Diameter of disk: 25cm Thickness: 1cm composition: pink granite

Follow-up on [my earlier question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629492/44126) about injecting 200 watts of power in granite.

Among the answers already provided, was the idea of using impact tools (jackhammer, plate compactor or vibrator motor). For my setup, I find the idea of a vibrator motor very interesting. I might pursue this option.

However, I am still not sure that most of the acoustic power will move radially from the center outwards. Do I need some kind of acoustic lens to focus the sound? Or could I drill radial holes in the plate, insert metal rods to propagate the sound? Some kind of waveguide?

Background of my experiment:

I would like to achieve anti-gravity!

I won't get into my theoretical reasoning, but I believe there is another component to the [Abraham-Lorentz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force) force that depends on the change of acceleration of a charged particle and the square of the charge. This equation describes the recoil force of a charged particle. My hunch is that there is another component that is perpendicular to the recoil.

Obtaining a change in acceleration is not hard using rotating bodies. I like granite because it contains minerals like biotite with iron positive ions in its crystalline structure. So you see where I go with this: shaking the iron ions using sound (while braking the rotating disk) should test my hypothesis.
Recently, I realized that my approach is not that far from what [Eugene Podkletnov](https://www.americanantigravity.com/eugene-podkletnov-2020-experiments) is doing now. He is building rotating disks with gold ions deposited on the surface. I believe we can achieve the same result using naturally occurring minerals.

My setup:

rotating granite disk at 330 rpm (going through braking, restarting in opposite direction)[image: there is a scale measuring a 3.95g weight not appearing on the photograph]
resonance speaker from PUI audio 40 watts

First of all, my apologies to all the cheese lovers of world. I had to to punch a hole in a granite cheese plate that I used as my rotating disk. I glued a resonance speaker at the center hoping to get longitudinal waves that go from the center to the outer diameter of the disk. I understand now that since the disk is the equivalent of the cone of a speaker, very little radial motion must be occurring.

Comment: If ion density is important, why not use salt or salt water? You could also easily accelerate salt water by having it flow in a curved pipe or by going from a large pipe to a small one. May I also ask about the theoretical basis?

Comment: Can I achieve a higher ion density with salt? Biotite contains Fe+3 ions a heavier element than Na+. Biotite is what they call a solid solution, I like very much the solid part...

Comment: If this does not work, I will use magnetite and build a disk of magnetite powder in epoxy that was placed in a magnetic field during curing.(the disk is ready, i need to do the experiment). I am currently preparing a presentation on how I came to the hypothesis of Abraham-Lorentz needing to be reinterpreted. No equation juggling involved. Past results of other experiments.

Comment: Hunch, you say? got an equation in mind? I have a bottle of whiskey. send me a personal message and we can share a virtual shot and I'll tell you about my antigravity research from 50 years ago, before I had taken any college-level physics courses.

Comment: Whiskey you say? I was thinking more of a microbrew..